# Unitary diagonalization of matrices

Tags: matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

Can someone tell me whether every square matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}$ unitarily diagonizable? If yes what is a necessary and sufficient condition for a square matrix $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ to be unitarily diagonalizable (please provide justification.)

Comment: it has to be [normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_operator), and a real and normal matrix is symmetric. the justification is the spectral theorem.

Comment: @user1952009 Why should a real and normal matrix be necessarily symmetric?

Comment: @Algebraic : I didn't find an elementary proof, but the spectral theorem implies that $A = P D P^*$ with $A$ is real $\implies$ $D$ is real $\implies A^T = A^* = (P D P^* )^* = P D P^* = A$. maybe an elementary proof would be to suppose that $A$ is not symmetric and show a contradiction (without the need of the spectral theorem)

Comment: @user1952009 OK for unitarily diagonalizable to a *real* matrix, but I somehow missed where it was required that $D$ should be real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean orthogonally diagonalizable so that you don't leave the real numbers. That is, I assume you ask for which $A \in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ we can find an orthogonal matrix $O$ such that $O^TAO$ is diagonal. This happens if and only if $A$ is symmetric, as guaranteed by the real [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem) .